How to Set gfortran Compiler Flags in a Complex Build System Involving Makefile.am, configure.ac, and setup.py?
Following this question, I am working on building a project that involves compiling FORTRAN 77 code using gfortran, but I am encountering a compilation error due to missing compiler flags. The specific error message is:
error: Command "/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -I/mnt/c/dev/JModelica/jmodelica_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/assimulo/thirdparty/hairer -I/mnt/c/dev/JModelica/jmodelica_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c -c assimulo/thirdparty/hairer/radau_decsol.f -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/assimulo/thirdparty/hairer/radau_decsol.o" failed with exit status 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1088: build-python-packages] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/dev/JModelica/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:514: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/dev/JModelica/build'
make: *** [Makefile:451: all] Error 2

I want to include the -ffixed-line-length-120 flag in the gfortran command to resolve this issue, but I am unsure where the gfortran flags are configured in the build system. The build system involves multiple configuration files such as Makefile.am, configure.ac, and setup.py.
Here’s a snippet from the generated build/Makefile related to building Python packages:
build-python-packages:
    mkdir -p $(assimulo_build_dir); \
    cd $(abs_top_srcdir)/external; \
    find Assimulo -type f |grep -v /.svn | grep -v .pyc | grep -v ~ |tar c -T - -f - | tar x -C $(assimulo_build_dir); \
    cd $(assimulo_build_dir)/Assimulo; \
    case $(build) in \
        *-cygwin*) \
        python setup.py install --with_openmp=True --superlu-home=$(abs_builddir)/superlu_build/ --sundials-home=$(SUNDIALS_HOME) --sundials-with-superlu=True --blas-home=$(abs_builddir)/blas_install/ --lapack-home=$(abs_builddir)/lapack_install/ --force-32bit="true" --extra-c-flags="-mincoming-stack-boundary=2" --prefix=$(assimulo_install_dir) ;; \
        *-mingw*) \
        python setup.py install --with_openmp=True --superlu-home=$(abs_builddir)/superlu_build/ --sundials-home=$(SUNDIALS_HOME) --sundials-with-superlu=True --blas-home=$(abs_builddir)/blas_install/ --lapack-home=$(abs_builddir)/lapack_install/ --force-32bit="true" $(NUMPY_NO_MSVCR_ARG) --extra-c-flags="-mincoming-stack-boundary=2" --prefix=$(assimulo_install_dir) ;; \
        *) \
        python setup.py install --with_openmp=True --superlu-home=$(abs_builddir)/superlu_build/ --sundials-home=$(SUNDIALS_HOME) --sundials-with-superlu=True --blas-home=$(abs_builddir)/blas_install/ --lapack-home=$(abs_builddir)/lapack_install/ --prefix=$(assimulo_install_dir) ;; \
    esac
    cd $(abs_top_srcdir)/Python/src; \
    python setup_pymodelica.py install --prefix=$(pymodelica_install_dir); \
    rm -rf build
    mkdir -p $(pyfmi_build_dir); \
    cd $(abs_top_srcdir)/external; \
    find PyFMI -type f |grep -v /.svn | grep -v .pyc | grep -v ~ |tar c -T - -f - | tar x -C $(pyfmi_build_dir); \
    cd $(pyfmi_build_dir)/PyFMI; \
    case $(build) in \
        *-cygwin*) \
        python setup.py install --fmil-home=$(abs_builddir)/FMIL_install/ --force-32bit="true" --extra-c-flags="-mincoming-stack-boundary=2" --prefix=$(pyfmi_install_dir) ;; \
        *-mingw*) \
        python setup.py install --fmil-home=$(abs_builddir)/FMIL_install/ --force-32bit="true" $(NUMPY_NO_MSVCR_ARG) --extra-c-flags="-mincoming-stack-boundary=2" --prefix=$(pyfmi_install_dir) ;; \
        *) \
        python setup.py install --fmil-home=$(abs_builddir)/FMIL_install/ --prefix=$(pyfmi_install_dir) ;; \
    esac
    rm -rf build
    cd $(abs_top_srcdir)/Python/src; \
    python setup_pyjmi.py install --prefix=$(pyjmi_install_dir); \
    rm -rf build

I suspect the Fortran compiler settings might be specified in one of these files, but I'm unsure how to trace or modify them appropriately.
Could anyone guide me on where to look or how to modify the build configuration to include additional gfortran flags? I am not sure where to look or what to look for.

There is, sadly, no general answer to the question. If someone used Autotools, you can hope they used a GNU "standard" variable like FFLAGS to accompany FC somewhere in the project, but all you can do is hard work or get lucky when examining the system. Are you asking for a "general" answer (for the utopia which doesn't exist), a "specific" answer for this one project, or an "algorithm" which can be applied by anyone to anywhere?

@francescalus, for the moment any solution, general/specific, would do. My best guess is that somewhere in the setup.py file those flags are cooked. But I could not find where.

It looks like you have Autotools in front and Python setuptools behind.  In that case, you should start by running ./configure -- help.  The output will tell you about environment variables and command-line options that affect how configure operates and what output it produces.  Some of it is boilerplate (which may nonetheless be useful)), but there may also be details specific to the particular package you're trying to build.

@JohnBollinger here is the output of the configure --help command, and indeed, there is an FFLAGS environment variable as Francescalus had predicted. Searching the codebase, the only relevant hits are in the configure.ac file that you may see here

So have you tried defining FFLAGS in configure's environment?  (FFLAGS=-ffixed-line-length-120 ./configure).

@JohnBollinger, the configure macro is autogenerated from configure.ac and Makefile.am using the autoreconf -fi command in this case. Any idea if/where in the m4 script I can add the FFLAGS=-ffixed-line-length-120 line, or are you suggesting that I preemptively create that variable in my bash environment?

@JohnBollinger I ran FFLAGS=-ffixed-line-length-120 ../configure --with-ipopt64=/usr and it did not work.

Supposing that you are trying to build an unmodified version of the project, it would be appropriate to raise this issue with the project's development team.  They are best positioned to assist, and if they are in fact active then I anticipate that they will want to assist.

@JohnBollinger well, the project was abandoned by Modelon a couple of years ago. I am the sole maintainer now!

In that case, until you replace the build system with something you can maintain yourself, your next best bet is probably to fix the code, especially if the build failures are related to modifications you made, and / or if they are only for a small number of files.  As it stands, this issue is too broadly scoped for SO.

found a soloution by changing extraargs["extra_f77_compile_args"] = extra_compile_flags[:] to extraargs["extra_f77_compile_args"] = extra_compile_flags[:] + ["-ffixed-line-length-120"]
